# source code of native implementation of android.graphics.Canvas class

Tags: android

Where can I find the source code of **native implementation** of android.graphics.Canvas class?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Canvas.java i leave its link for visitors of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have downloaded android source code (not sdk source code) from [here](http://source.android.com). The native implemetation of Canvas is located here: frameworks\base\core\jni\android\graphics

Comment: no canvas class exist in this path.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can view it directly in the Git repository without downloading the whole source tree:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android/graphics/Canvas.cpp

Answer (score -2):

Here You could find source codes:

http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

But I cannot guarantee that these sources are complete

Comment: Thanks. I want implementations of **native** methods such as drawTextOnPath(...)

Comment: like this one? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/graphics/Canvas.java#Canvas.native_drawTextOnPath%28int%2Cchar[]%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%2Cint%2Cint%29

Comment: No. This is Java! Go to the end of that class. You will see some native methods. I want implementation of those methods: `private static native void native_drawTextOnPath...`

Comment: The only thing I found about native API is this: http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/#opengl-es